# Print out 3 HashMaps - Java

Tags: java

I have this code currently;

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Products {
    HashMap<Integer, String> id = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Integer, String> dtion = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Integer, Double> amount = new HashMap<>();
```

I have then added example data into each HashMap through the constructor. I have these three HashMaps as i want to print out the ProductID, along with the description and price. This means that the ProductID will be the same for the same item throughout the 3 HashMaps. How do i print out these items In a single line? E.g Item1, This is an item, 3.20.  Item2, This is another item, 5.10
instead of Printing out all the stuff out from the first HashMap followed by the second and followed by the third.

Comment: Why are you aiming at having only one line?

Comment: Why don't use a single `Map`?

Comment: Add these maps to a parent map. Loop through the parent map. Put the values in the StringBuffer, print it finally.

Answer (score 2):

It would make more sense to create a `Product` class having `productID`, `description` and `price`, and only use a single `HashMap` instead of 3.

```
public class Product
{
    private String productID;
    private String description;
    private double price;

    public Product (String productID, String description, double price)
    {
        this.productID = productID;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return productID + ", " + description + ", " + price;
    }
}

public class Products 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        HashMap<Integer, Product> products = new HashMap<>();
        products.put (1, new Product("Item1","This is an item", 3.20));
        products.put (2, new Product("Item2","This is another item", 5.10));
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: How would i go about doing that?

Comment: But by doing it this way - productID, description and price can only hold one value right? I'm wanting to add in numerous items, at least 10. So i'd want 10 values in productID, 10 in description and 10 under price.

Comment: @james11 You can add to your Map as many instances of Product as you need, each having its own ID, description and price.

Comment: Getting an error on the products.put lines, Cannot make a static reference

Comment: @james11 I changed the `products` Map to be a local variable in the main method, which solves the error. Another way to solve it is by keeping it where it is and declaring it static.

Comment: But by making it a local variable, how do i System.out.println the products, and add new ones in through a method?

Comment: @james11 It doesn't have to be local. It can be a static member of the `Products` class or an instance member of that class. If it's an instance member, you can't access it directly from a static method (such as main) without creating an instance of `Products` first.

Comment: But i've tried returning the values of the HashMap by having a method print products.values() but it says it cannot be found. So how would i return all of the products?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Map<Integer, Product>` rather than this approach. In `Product`, you can store all the fields you want/need. Example:

```
public class Product {
    private String productId;
    private String description;
    private double price;

    //getters and setters...

    //toString method
}
```

Then, in your `Products` class you will only need a single map:

```
public class Products {
    Map<Integer, Product> productMap = new HashMap<>();
    //rest of the class...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you do it with HashMaps:

```
public String getProductString(final int pKey){
 return "ID: "+productId.get(pKey)+" Description: "+description.get(pKey)+" Price: "+String.valueOf(price.get(pKey));
}
```

if you make your own class:

```
public class Product{

 private double price;
 private String productId;
 private String description;

 public Product(final double pPrice, final String pProductId, final String pDescription){
  this.price = pPrice;
  this.productId = pProductId;
  this.description = pDescription;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString(){
  return "ID: "+productId+" Description: "+description+" Price: "+price
 }

}
```

if you ve got an instance of the class Product you can call toString() on it and it will return the values